# Overwrite datasets in scratch geodatabase arcpy?

Tags: arcpy

I've created a scratch file geodatabase, intended to be a temporary location where I can reproject the necessary datasets. The script runs fine the first go around. However, it fails on the second try since the feature classes in the scratch file geodatabase already exist.

What is the best way to overwrite or delete the data sets (sourceNAD27, sourceNAD83 and sourceWGS84) in my scratch file geodatabase?

```
       # source is the full path to the datasets in the sde
        sourceNAD27 = os.path.join(sourceDB,'{schema}.{table}'.format(schema=sourceDict['schema'], table=sourceDict['table']))

        # copy features into a temporary location
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(sourceNAD27,os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchGDB),'sourceNAD27')

        # project from GCS_North_American_1927 to GCS_North_American_1983
        arcpy.Project_management (os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchGDB, 'sourceNAD27'), os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchGDB, 'sourceNAD83'), 4269, "NAD_1927_To_NAD_1983_NADCON", 4267)

        # project from GCS_North_American_1983 to WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere
        arcpy.Project_management (os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchGDB, 'sourceNAD83'), os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchGDB, 'sourceWGS84'), 3857, "WGS_1984_(ITRF00)_To_NAD_1983", 4269)

        # target is the full path to the datasets in the sde
        target = os.path.join(targetDB,'{schema}.{table}'.format(schema=targetDict['schema'], table=targetDict['table']))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`

Comment: I did not know even that is possible. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

I also advise some alternatives to this method as given in [this link](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Overwrite%20datasets%20in%20geodatabase%20arcpy).